# How do I get the users activity discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

**Problem:** I have been trying to add a "Activity" field to my info command, and its not working.

**Expected result:** Responds with the other stuff, along with the Activity field, showing what the user is doing.

**Actual response:** Shows everything else correctly, except the Activity field, which says `undefined`/`null`.

**Code:**

```js
if (command == "info") {
  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  let member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args[1]) || message.guild.member(message.author)
    const Roles = new Array()
    message.guild.roles.cache.forEach(role => {
      if (member.roles.cache.find(r => r.id == role.id)) {
        Roles.push(role)
      }
        })
    console.log(member.presence)
  embed.setAuthor(user.tag, member.user.avatarURL())
  embed.setTitle(` Welcome to ${user.username}'s Profile!`)
  embed.addField('#️⃣ Tag:', member.user.tag)
  embed.addField(' Joined Guild at:', member.user.joinedAt)
  embed.addField(' Joined Discord at:', member.user.cretedAt
)
if (!member.presence.activities) {
  embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', 'Not playing anything')
} else {
  embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', `${member.presence.activities.type} ${member.presence.activities.name}\n${member.presence.activities.details}\n${member.presence.activities.state}`)
}
  embed.addField(' Platform:', member.presence.clientStatus)
  embed.addField(' Bot:', user.bot)
  embed.addField(' Roles:', Roles.join(' | '))
  embed.setFooter('Bot made with discord.js')
  message.channel.send(embed)
  }
```

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(member.presence.activities)` to see if the member actually has an activity?

Comment: I have done ``console.log(member.presence)`` and it showed this
`Presence {
  // Other stuff here
  status: 'dnd',
  activities: [
    Activity {
      name: 'test',
      type: 'PLAYING',
      url: null,
      details: 'test',
      state: 'test',
      applicationID: null,
      timestamps: null,
      party: null,
      assets: null,
      syncID: undefined,
      flags: [ActivityFlags],
      emoji: null,
      createdTimestamp: 1627426677284
    }
  ],
  clientStatus: { web: 'dnd' }
}
`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Presence.activities`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence) is an array of [`Activity`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity).

```js
// Add check for empty activities array
if (!member.presence.activities || member.presence.activities.length == 0) {
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', 'Not playing anything')
} else {
    const activity = member.presence.activities[0];
    embed.addField('⚽️ Activity:', `${activity.type} ${activity.name}\n${activity.details}\n${activity.state}`);
}
```

Most of the time you will only need the first item of the array. Because you rarely see users with multiple activities.